# android HTML5 video tag honeycomb

Tags: html, video, tags, android-3.0-honeycomb

I use android honeycomb 3.2 and I'm able to play video with `hardwareaccelerated = true` and set a webchromeclient. 
But I would enable and disable hardware acceleration before play a `<video>` and after video is finished because js and css3 work not well.
What event can I intercept?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are the following two listeners.

For start:

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { //code });
```

For end:

```
videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() { //code });
```